# How to show menu tab only for certain node type?

Tags: 9, navigation

I have the following,

In the `routing.yml`

```
mymodule.cache_clear:
  path: '/node/{node}/cache'
  defaults:
    _form:  '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\APICacheClearForm'
    _title: 'Cache Clear'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    entity: \d+
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node_type:
        type: entity:node
        bundle:
          - blog
```

In the `links.task.yml`

```
mymodule.cache_clear:
  title: 'Cache Clear'
  route_name: topgun_api.cache_clear
  route_parameters: { node_type: blog }
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

I don't see the tab being shown only on blog content type.

Is it not possible to accomplish this without using `_custom_access`?

Answer (score 1):

The code below work for me.

in the `routing.yml`

```
mymodule.cache_clear:
  path: '/node/{node}/cache'
  defaults:
    _form:  '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\APICacheClearForm'
    _title: 'Cache Clear'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    node: \d+
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
        bundle:
          - blog
```

In the links.task.yml

```
mymodule.cache_clear:
  title: 'Cache Clear'
  route_name: mymodule.cache_clear
  route_parameters: { node_type: blog }
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not possible to accomplish this without using `_custom_access`?

The other alternative is:

**mymodule.links.task.yml**

```
mymodule.cache_clear:
  title: 'Cache Clear'
  route_name: mymodule.cache_clear
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```

**mymodule.module**

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu_local_actions_alter().
*/
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  // Load the node entity based on the current route parameters.
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');

  // Remove if it's not a blog type.
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface
    && $node->getType() != 'blog') {
     unset($data['tabs'][0]['mymodule.cache_clear']);
  }
}
```